# Look if file contains a specific string and then read that line

Tags: c#, foreach

I am using this foreach loop to search for files in a directory and then read them.

```
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(location, "*.MAI"))
```

Inside this loop I want to search for the line in the file that contains the word "Sended". Is there a way to look for this word and then read that line?

Comment: I don't know `.MAI`, are those text files? And if so, ASCII, UTF-8? How big (on average / at most) are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
var location = @"<your location>";
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(location, "*.MAI"))
{
    var findedLines = File.ReadAllLines(file)
                          .Where(l => l.Contains("Sended"));
}
```

If you work with big files, you should use **ReadLines** method, because when you use **ReadLines**, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use **ReadAllLines**, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array.

Another example from msdn:

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(location, "*.MAI")
            from line in File.ReadLines(file)
            where line.Contains("Sended")
            select new
            {
                File = file,
                Line = line
            };
```

Full information, look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383503.aspx

Comment: Especially for very big files, use `ReadLines()`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you for your comment, I agree with you, so add this information to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If .MAI files are Textfiles try the following:

```
       foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(location, "*.MAI"))
        {
            foreach (string Line in File.ReadAllLines(file))
            {
                if (Line.Contains("Sended"))
                { 
                    //Do your stuff here
                }
            }
        }
```